# How to solve customHooks call signature error in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context, use-context

I am new in typescript. I tried to solve call signature error but I couldn't figure it out.

I try to use custom hooks  which it takes a context props and then return the contex like below

```
export const useCardContext = (): ContextProps => {
  const context = useContext(CardContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(
      `Card compound components  cannot be rendered outside the Card component`
    );
  }
  return context;
};
```

and here is my context props
and created context

```
interface ContextProps {
  isAccordionActive: boolean;
  isModalActive: boolean;
  toggleAccordion: Function;
  toggleModal: Function;
}

const CardContext = createContext<ContextProps>({
  isAccordionActive: false,
  isModalActive: false,
  toggleAccordion: () => null,
  toggleModal: () => null,
});
```

But when I try to use useCardContext hooks inside of another function I get this error.

```
const data = useCardContext(); // Type 'Context<ContextProps>' has no call signatures. ts 2349
```

So what I did to solve this, if I export CardContext and use like below I didn't get any error.

```
//import usecontext and CardContext
const context = useContext(CardContext); //it is fine as expected.
```

My question is I would like to use the custom hooks (useCardContext) without the error. How I can solve this issue?

Comment: It sounds like you've misnamed something in your imports and exports.  Maybe got confused about the default export.  I don't get any error when calling `useCardContext()`  https://tsplay.dev/3NDO4w  The error `Type 'Context<ContextProps>' has no call signatures` means that you are calling the context object instead of the hook.

Comment: You are right. I imported like default way. but should be in curly parentheses. Thanks for comment. I didn't realize it ahah